# How to skip XML parsing errors when accessing WFS endpoint using ogr2ogr?

Tags: gdal, wfs, ogr2ogr, gml

I am downloading data from a WFS endpoint using [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html). The WFS endpoint: https://wxs-gpu.mongeoportail.ign.fr/externe/39wtxmgtn23okfbbs1al2lz3/wfs.

The name of the layer I care about: `wfs_du:zone_urba`. It's Title is: `Zonage du document d'urbanisme`. QGIS screenshot:

[image]

(You can get here via clicking: `Layer` -> `Add Layer` -> `Add WFS Layer...`, and then add the above URL as a connection)

Using QGIS, I verified that this layer is indeed accessible:

[image]

and that it has 1072933 features in total (right click on layer name in the Layers panel, then *Show Feature Count*).

I can download 10000 featues in one go. To download the features starting with the one with id 123456 (example case), I do:

```
url="https://wxs-gpu.mongeoportail.ign.fr/externe/39wtxmgtn23okfbbs1al2lz3/wfs"
ogr2ogr test.gpkg WFS:"$url?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&startIndex=123456" \
        -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM 'wfs_du:zone_urba'"
```

This works nicely, I get `test.gpkg` with 10000 features. My plan was to start from `startIndex` 0, download 10000 features, then download the next batch using `startIndex` 10000, and so on. However, when I arrive to `startIndex` 840000:

```
url="https://wxs-gpu.mongeoportail.ign.fr/externe/39wtxmgtn23okfbbs1al2lz3/wfs"
ogr2ogr test.gpkg WFS:"$url?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&startIndex=840000" \
        -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM 'wfs_du:zone_urba'"
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1: XML parsing of GML file failed : reference to invalid character number at line 11, column 12991735
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation from sql statement.
ERROR 1: sqlite3_exec(CREATE TRIGGER "trigger_insert_feature_count_SELECT" AFTER INSERT ON "SELECT" BEGIN UPDATE gpkg_ogr_contents SET feature_count = feature_count + 1 WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('SELECT'); END;) failed: no such table: main.SELECT
ERROR 1: sqlite3_exec(CREATE TRIGGER "trigger_delete_feature_count_SELECT" AFTER DELETE ON "SELECT" BEGIN UPDATE gpkg_ogr_contents SET feature_count = feature_count - 1 WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('SELECT'); END;) failed: no such table: main.SELECT
```

If I try to write to a GeoJSON instead:

```
url="https://wxs-gpu.mongeoportail.ign.fr/externe/39wtxmgtn23okfbbs1al2lz3/wfs"
ogr2ogr test.geojson WFS:"$url?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&startIndex=840000" \
        -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM 'wfs_du:zone_urba'"
```

I have only the first part of the error message:

```
ERROR 1: XML parsing of GML file failed : reference to invalid character number at line 11, column 12991735
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation from sql statement.
```

So I think this is the core issue. I also tried to use the [`-skipfailures`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-skipfailures) option:

```
url="https://wxs-gpu.mongeoportail.ign.fr/externe/39wtxmgtn23okfbbs1al2lz3/wfs"
ogr2ogr test.gpkg WFS:"$url?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&startIndex=840000" \
        -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM 'wfs_du:zone_urba'" \
        -skipfailures
```

But I get the same error message:

```
ERROR 1: XML parsing of GML file failed : reference to invalid character number at line 11, column 12991735
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation from sql statement.
```

If this error is only concerning a handful of features, downloading the remaining ones from the 1072933 of them is still helpful.

I believe this is possible somehow, as if I start the downloading at a later point (let's say 912345):

```
url="https://wxs-gpu.mongeoportail.ign.fr/externe/39wtxmgtn23okfbbs1al2lz3/wfs"
ogr2ogr test.gpkg WFS:"$url?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&startIndex=912345" \
        -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM 'wfs_du:zone_urba'"
```

I get a gpkg file with 10000 features.

I could download almost all of the data if it would be possible to identify which features are wrong, before launching the download script. Then, I could query for all features up to and above that id. However, the exact id where the error occurs does not seem to be constant. For a while, it seemed the error is between id 848020 and 848030, because this URL:

https://wxs-gpu.mongeoportail.ign.fr/externe/39wtxmgtn23okfbbs1al2lz3/wfs?service=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=wfs_du:zone_urba&version=1.0.0&startIndex=848020&MAXFEATURES=10

returned:

[image]

but now it returns a proper GML page:

[image]

which I think suggest that the id which causes the XML parsing error is not constant. This is why I'm looking for a way to skip the features with causing XML parsing error, without me having to hardcode which are these features.

**How can I tell `ogr2ogr` to skip the features affected by the XML parsing error & continue downloading?**

Comment: WFS 1.0.0 doesn't support paging, you need to use WFS 2.0.0 to have paging

Comment: Since WFS 2 supports paging, it would be natural not to bother with `startIndex` and just download the whole dataset in one go. This fails because of the same error outlined above, but only does so after a long time, since the download starts at `startIndex` 0, not 840000. I think it is easier to debug the issue if it is quickly reproducible.

Comment: have a look at just the feature by downloading it in a browser or with curl - the obvious work around is to ask for all the features upto and above that ID

Comment: That could work, but somehow the id where the error occurs does not seem constant. I'll update the post to clarify this.

Comment: The WFS 1.0.0 *standard* does not support paging but some WFS servers have extented the standard. For example with this server startindex does work. Try https://wxs-gpu.mongeoportail.ign.fr/externe/39wtxmgtn23okfbbs1al2lz3/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=wfs_du:zone_urba&maxfeatures=1&startindex=20

Comment: There happens some failure on the server side. In your last screen capture you can see that the data should contain numbers that present the coordinates of a geometry, but instead the server sends something like `...DU_372`. There is nothing you can do on the client side with ogr2ogr. Contact the service provider. It is not possible to skip such error because for parsing XML even the last ends of the elements must be read.

Comment: "It is not possible to skip such error because for parsing XML even the last ends of the elements must be read." - this is very helpful, thanks. I think this answers the question. If you are confident there is no way around, I think it would be a good answer. I will leave the question open though for a while, to be more sure no one else has an solution disproving this position.

Comment: When I request 10 features from startindex of 848020 (https://wxs-gpu.mongeoportail.ign.fr/externe/39wtxmgtn23okfbbs1al2lz3/wfs?service=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=wfs_du:zone_urba&version=2.0.0&startIndex=848020&count=10) I get a valid XML response starting from a feature with id that is not 2771268 (from your example), in fact it changes per request so it appears that the service is dynamically adding features, which will mean it'll be difficult to quickly reproduce your error (or report which feature is in error).  You could try a GetFeatureById request based on your original error.